# Автоматическое создание поддоменов на Apache

Tags: apache, настройка, php

Доброго времени, ХэшКодеры.

На моем сайте есть (будет) услуга создания поддоменов. Немного подробнее.

Допустим мой сайт http://site.ru . Если пользователь хочет себе страничку, он может создать что-то вроде http://my.site.ru или http://magazin.site.ru и др. Как мне настроить вебсервер на автоматическую генерацию таких адресов и какие инструменты для этого понадобятся? ОС локалки - Windows 7, рабочая машина на Debian или Ubuntu (где проще настроить будет?).

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: Если пользователь хочет себе страничку
Вы имеете ввиду виртуальный хостинг или систему блогов с красивыми адресами?

Comment: ReinRaus, виртуальный хостинг

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью `mod_vhost_alias` можно создать конфигурацию, которая будет автоматически выводить поддомены, исходя из структуры файлов и папок на сервер. Пример для Windows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.ru
    ServerAlias *.site.ru
    VirtualDocumentRoot "D:/www/vhosts/site.ru/%1"
</VirtualHost>
```

Здесь xxx.site.ru указывает на D:/www/vhosts/site.ru/xxx/.

Answer (score 3):

Используй mod_vhost_alias для Apache2. Информации и документации по нему хватает. Production-сервер естественно устанавливайте на Linux. Сам файл модуля называется libapache2-mod-vhost-hash-alias. В настройке довольно прост.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то [**такое**](http://uweb.ws/)?

---

Если да, создаем в панели **dns-запись**:

[image]

В **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.uweb\.ws$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=%1 [L,QSA]
```

В **index.php**:

```
<?
var_export($_GET['site']); // =)
```

Готово!

Comment: А как будет выглядеть структура папок для созданного поддомена?