# Онлайн подключение поддомена

Tags: php, javascript, bash

Здравствуйте! Как сделать? Например я открыл сайт по аренде магазина, и хочу что бы пользователь сам регистрировал поддомен. Например, заходит на сайт, проходит регистрацию,и регистрирует поддомен (к примеру, shop.hashcode.ru) и производит оплату.

Может есть готовый скрипт для этого?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автоматическое создание поддоменов на Apache](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93809/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-apache)

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь директорию поддомена на уровне с доменом - поддомен готов, по крайней мере на апаче, по моему, так можно делать.

Также этот вопрос обсуждался [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/93809/178576).

Так же можно переписывать адреса с помощью .htaccess и через get\post перенаправлять на директорию или что делать.
Вариантов много, но на чистом PHP этого не решить.

Готовые скрипты тоже есть, да и стоимость их отосительно небольшая. Либо мб что нулленое найдете