# Создание поддоменов на сервере

Tags: apache, домен, php, сервер, поддомены

Ку.

Как можно сделать, чтоб поддомены создавались  автоматически? Ну вот, допустим, имеется сервер, на нем сайт http://сайт.ru, а на сайте форма регистрации аккаунта с регистрацией поддомена. После регистрации поддомен доступен http://поддомен.сайт.ru, сделать, чтоб без .htaccess, а так, чтоб норм, как положено, через httpd.conf?

"Инфы много", - скажут многие, но я потерялся в ней. Может быть, пример кто покажет либо линки на топики?

Comment: [http://artkiev.com/blog/apache-add-subdomain.htm](http://artkiev.com/blog/apache-add-subdomain.htm)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автоматическое создание поддоменов на Apache](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93809/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-apache)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в httpd.conf дописывать виртуальный хост с примерно такими параметрами.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "..../папака поддомена/public_html"
ServerName поддомен
<Directory "..../папака поддомена/public_html">
Allow from all
Options -Indexes #По желанию
</Directory>

ErrorLog ....../logs/поддомен-error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ....../logs/поддомен-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Лучше писать не в httpd.conf, а создавать в какой-нибудь дирректории файлы, вышеописанного содержания, с именем, например `поддомен.conf`
Для этого достаточно определиться с дирректорией и добавить в конец `httpd.conf` следующую строку: `Include /путь/до/дирректории/*.conf`

После создания файла, или "дописывания" вышеуказанных строк, стоит делать `service apache2 graceful`